# How do I map prisma object in a NextJS 13 app router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma

I use prisma (with sqlite) and have User model store id, name, email.
In the file, /alluser/page.tsx, I have this function to read for prisma data.

```
export async function getAllUsers(){
const prisma = new PrismaClient()
const users = await prisma.user.findMany()
    
 return{
 users
}
```

from the function I got user object in the form of

`[{id:1, email:'email1', name: 'name1'},{id:2, email:'email2', name: 'name2'}]`

and in export default function I use

```
export default function AllUser() {

    const users = getAllUsers()
    
    return (
      <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
        <h1> All User </h1>
            {users.map((user) => (
            <li key={user.id}>
              <div>{user.name}</div>
              <div>{user.email}</div>
            </li>
          ))}
      </main>
    )
}
```

I tried console log users from the function AllUser() and I got

`Promise {   { users: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },   [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 1088649,   [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 1088647,   [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined, ...`

I tried using parse and stringify but still got
`TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...data.map...')`

Comment: You return an object from `getAllUsers`, it does not have `map` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you forget to `await` for promise:

`get-all-users.ts`:

```
export async function getAllUsers(){
  const prisma = new PrismaClient()
  const users = await prisma.user.findMany()
    
  return users
  
}
```

Page component should be async
`page.tsx`:

```
   export default async function AllUser() {

    const users = await getAllUsers()
    
    return (
      <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
        <h1> All User </h1>
            {users.map((user) => (
            <li key={user.id}>
              <div>{user.name}</div>
              <div>{user.email}</div>
            </li>
          ))}
      </main>
    )
}
```